# Ember-data peekRecord returns null

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Ember inspector shows the correct user, but

```
user: Ember.computed(function(){
    let uid = this.get('user_id'); //the correct ID
    return this.store.peekRecord('user', uid);
}),
```

Returns null. Might this have something to do with attempting this call outside of the model hook? Really stuck on this!

Thanks so much!

**Edit:** torazaburo solved the problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36321115/ember-data-dependent-keys-undefined). It was a problem with promises.

Comment: Well, the problem is almost certainly that `uid` does not have a correct value. Where does it come from? Based on your other question, it might be a promise. You cannot use a promise here; you must use its returned value, which in turn means that all else being equal `user` cannot be a computed property, but itself must be asynchronous.

Comment: Where is this code, in a route, controller or..?